# OSError:lib64/libm.so.6:version `GLIBC_2.27' not found /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensmile/core/bin/linux/libSMILEapi.so

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm working with AWS Sagemaker and I'm trying to update a lambda created with a docker image. Please help me with this issue:

```
[ERROR] OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensmile/core/bin/linux/libSMILEapi.so)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
 File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
 File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
 File "", line 850, in exec_module
 File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 15, in
   from get_prediction import get_prediction
 File "/var/task/get_prediction.py", line 7, in
   from feature_extraction import get_features
 File "/var/task/feature_extraction.py", line 19, in
   import opensmile as opnsmile
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensmile/init.py", line 6, in
   from opensmile.core.smile import (
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensmile/core/smile.py", line 13, in
   from opensmile.core.SMILEapi import (
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensmile/core/SMILEapi.py", line 23, in
   smileapi = cdll.LoadLibrary(smileapi_path)
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/ctypes/init.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
   return self._dlltype(name)
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/ctypes/init.py", line 374, in init
   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

*** Server AWS SageMaker system. System information:
sh-4.2$ uname -r 4.14.248-129.473.amzn1.x86_64

***Docker image:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 as build-image

ARG FUNCTION_DIR="./app/"
ARG NUMBA_CACHE_DIR="/tmp"

RUN yum install -y tar xz yum-utils
RUN yum remove  cmake
RUN yum update -y

# start install sudo, wget and openssl, which is required for building CMake
RUN yum install sudo wget openssl-devel -y

### start install development tools
RUN sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
RUN gcc --version
RUN g++ --version

# Download, build and install cmake
RUN wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.18/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
RUN cd cmake-3.18.0/ && \
       ./bootstrap && \
       make && \
       make install

### start opensmile compilation and 
RUN wget  https://github.com/audeering/opensmile/archive/master.zip && \
                                         unzip master.zip && \
                                         cd opensmile-master/ && \
                                         ./build.sh 
### end opensmile compilation

## start glibc installation
RUN mkdir ~/glibc227
RUN cd ~/glibc227
RUN wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.27.tar.gz
RUN tar zxvf glibc-2.27.tar.gz && \
                 cd glibc-2.27 && \
                   mkdir build && \
                      cd build && \
  ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.27  && \
                      make -j4 && \
                  make install 
# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN yum update -y

RUN yum install -y git cmake libmad-devel libsndfile-devel gd-devel boost-devel

RUN yum install -y install apt-utils gcc libpq-dev libsndfile-dev

RUN yum update -y
RUN python -m pip install -U scikit-image
RUN python -m pip install boto3
COPY ${FUNCTION_DIR} ./
COPY requirements.txt ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN python -m pip install \
        --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric

RUN show-installed 
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

In the lambda I add this line:

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/opt/glibc-2.27/lib:' + os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']



def lambda_handler(event, context):
...
```

Please help me

"openSMILE feature
extraction toolkit. Version 2.0 now unites feature extraction
paradigms from speech, music, and general sound events
with basic video features for multi-modal processing. Descriptors from audio and video can be processed jointly in a
single framework allowing for time synchronization of parameters, on-line incremental processing as well as off-line and
batch processing, and the extraction of statistical functionals (feature summaries), such as moments, peaks, regression
parameters, etc. Postprocessing of the features includes statistical classifiers such as support vector machine models or
file export for popular toolkits such as Weka or HTK. Available low-level descriptors include popular speech, music and
video features including Mel-frequency and similar cepstral
and spectral coefficients, Chroma, CENS, auditory model
based loudness, voice quality, local binary pattern, color, and
optical flow histograms. Besides, voice activity detection,
pitch tracking and face detection are supported. openSMILE
is implemented in C++, using standard open source libraries
for on-line audio and video input. It is fast, runs on Unix
and Windows platforms"

Comment: The C library is sufficiently core to a Linux system that I wouldn't try to install it from source like you have here.  Your base image is all but guaranteed to have a libc installation already (GNU libc, even, if it's not Alpine-based); is there a reason you're trying to install it separately?

Comment: Opensmile requires at least  CMake 3.5.1.